# SQL Error login with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, mysql-error-1005

Hi I am facing a problem with running `exercise file` of `asp.net Quiz engine` when try to make `login as admin` this message show up in the browser

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

[image]

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/335874/A-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occur

Answer (score 2):

The first place I would look would would be My Computer > Manage  and then click on Services.  Scroll down to SQL Server, and verify that the service is started (I noticed on my development environments that occasionally my service will not start event though it is set to automatically start.  Also, are you running a default or named instance of SQL Server?  If your service is started, and you think your connection string is correct, could you include your connection string (obviously omit any username/password credentials) so that I can see what that looks like?